# vscode how to include leveldb installed on my Mac by HomeBrew

Tags: visual-studio-code, homebrew, intellisense

I installed leveldb my mac using homebrew and tried to import it to a cpp project in vscode. However, when trying to import the header file db.h as below:

`#include "leveldb/db.h"`

The IntelliSense could not find the file. Editing the includePath in c_cpp_properties.json also did not help:

```json
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/bin/**",
            "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/**",
        ],
```

As "brew info leveldb" outputs:

Key-value storage library with ordered mapping
https://github.com/google/leveldb/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/leveldb/1.23 (31 files, 830.7KB) *

So I included /opt/homebrew/Cellar/** but that did not help.

Could anyone point out what the problem is and what potential workarounds there are?

Comment: why not figure out where the include directory is and use that instead of globbing?

Comment: Tried that as well: 

                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/bin/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/leveldb/1.23/include/leveldb"
            ]
where the last path is where the header files reside but no luck

Comment: It's conventional to name the directory that you pass as an include directory "include". If you want to `#include "leveldb/db.h"`, then it you should use `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/leveldb/1.23/include` instead. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's conventional to name the directory that you pass as an include directory "include". If you want to `#include "leveldb/db.h"`, then it you should use `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/leveldb/1.23/include` instead.